# Kernel 3.13.7-1 arch cant boot

Tags: archlinux

I am using gummiboot on a macbook air mid 2012 model. Has only arch Linux on it. Can't seem to boot into my arch, with both uuid and absolute device name. Always falling into rootfs prompt.

Switching to refind didn't help either.
Where can I start looking for more information on whether its recognising the hard disk or not?

Comment: To see what partitions there are, type ls /dev | grep sda at the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full explanation of the situation:

I have a Macbook Air 11" mid 2012 with **only** Arch Linux on it. I don't want OSX. I don't want to install any other distro (Fedora etc).
I had a Arch Bang installation with GNOME on it. My linux would load using Gummiboot. I did a `pacman -Syu` and that brought in 3.13.7-1 arch kernel. I rebooted to get "waiting for 10 seconds for root device..." message and this would lead to the rootfs prompt. Looking at [this article on arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179043) I understood there was some issue between gummiboot and the latest 3.13.7 kernel and the suggestion was to switch to refind bootloader.

I did but I was still falling to rootfs prompt.
Then I decided to bypass bootloaders altogether and use efibootmgr to directly tell uefi firmware that ["hey look this is my linux installation, load it"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB#Directly.2C_without_boot_manager). So bootloader is no longer a suspect.

Now, I was initially chrooting like this via a live cd:

(From the live cd terminal)...
`mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi`

`mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc`

`mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys`

`mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev`

`mount -o bind /dev/pts /dev/pts`

`modprobe efivarfs`

`chroot /mnt`

(and then from inside the chroot)...

`pacman -Syy linux`

`mkinitcpio -p linux`

`exit`

(inside live cd terminal)...

`umount /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/sys /mnt/dev /mnt/dev/pts /mnt/proc /mnt/boot/efi /mnt`

But **still** I was getting the rootfs prompt. 
[Solution was to chroot like this:](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2013-02/07-archlinux_fixing_init_ramdisk)

`mount /dev/sda3 /mnt`

`chroot /mnt /bin/bash`

`mount -t proc proc /proc`

`mount -t sysfs sys /sys`

`mount -t devtmpfs udev /dev`

`mkinitcpio -p linux`

`exit`

`umount /mnt/proc /mnt/dev /mnt/sys /mnt`

`reboot`

I am not sure what is different from what I was doing to this but it sure worked. I wish I hadn't reinstalled my OS. I should have stuck to my belief that you can rescue more often than reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when grub-mkconfig detects the wrong hard drive so it passes the kernel the wrong parameters.

To fix it, mount your root partition from the rescue shell with `mount /dev/sdaX /newroot`, replacing X with the partition number of your root filesystem from when you installed, and then hit Ctrl-D. This should start the boot sequence.

Then, you can manually edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and find the line that says `linux (hd0,gptX)/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sdaX`, and replace root=??? with the correct root device (most likely /dev/sda2 given the Macbook and GPT info).

Comment: I am not using grub. I am booting without a bootloader (efibootmgr method).

Comment: @sindhus, you should still be able to boot into your system using the described method, though. Try it and you should be able to edit the boot parameters to the kernel.

Comment: I did an ls at the rootfs prompt and see no sdX listing of partitions. No matter how I load my root partition (through bootloader, without bootloader, with label, without label) using 3.13.8-1-arch kernel, it can't seem to find my root parition, even though its there.

Since I single boot I used efibootmgr with `efibootmgr -d /dev/sda -p 1 -c -L "arch" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=/dev/sda2 rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"` to directly boot but still I land at rootfs prompt.